# autocomple in angular js getting error

Tags: angularjs

I am not familiar with angular js for doing demo about autocomplete on angular js; it getting error about autocomplete is not functiion; see below code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Autocomplete Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/autocomplete.css">

</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h1><span class="thin">AngularJS:</span> - Demo</h1>
</header>
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
        <input type="text" ng-model="foo" auto-complete /> Foo = {{foo}}
    </div>
</div>



<footer>
    made by
</footer>

<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('MyModule', []).controller('DefaultCtrl', ['$scope',           function($scope) {}])

    .factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function() {
        return {
            getSource: function() {

                return ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
            }
        }
    }])

    .directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

                elem.autocomplete({
                    source: autoCompleteDataService.getSource(),
                    minLength: 2
                });
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

I have tried my best and surfing on the google as well as stackoverflow but I didn't get the solution.

**See error image autocomplete is not a function :**

[image]

Comment: i think you need to install autocomplete plugin in your application